# Python Solution for 392. Is Subsequence

Tags: python, string, dynamic-programming

I have solved solution 392 on LeetCode and one of the topics listed for it is Dynamic Programming. Looking at my code and other solutions online, I wonder what part of the solution is categorized as pertaining to Dynamic Programming. I would appreciate it if someone could enlighten me and help me have a better understanding of this.

The solution explanation is paywalled for me on LeetCode as I don't have premium, so I am trying to open source this understanding.

Solution:

```
def isSubsequence(self, s: str, t: str) -> bool:
    if len(s) == 0:
        return True
    if len(t) == 0:
        return False
    temp = ''
    count = 0
    for i in t:
        if count < len(s) and i == s[count]:
            temp += i
            count += 1
    if temp == s:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Link: https://leetcode.com/problems/is-subsequence/

Comment: Your approach is an example of a  [two pointer algorithm](https://towardsdatascience.com/two-pointer-approach-python-code-f3986b602640) rather than dynamic programming.  However, it is as efficient as dynamic programming i.e. O(n).

Comment: @DarrylG: That makes sense thanks, do you know how will this solution be implemented using dynamic programming?

Comment: yes, I'll try adding an answer to explain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As commented the posted solution is Your approach is an example of a [two pointer algorithm](https://towardsdatascience.com/two-pointer-approach-python-code-f3986b602640)

To create a [Dynamic Programming problems](https://medium.com/cs-dojo/an-introduction-to-dynamic-programming-89fdd3549d54) solution we can be broken into three steps

1. Find the first solution (base case)
2. Analyze the solution
3. Optimize the solution

**Step 1: First solution**

Here's a recursive solution top/down solution that solves the problem.

- Recursive solution breaks into subproblems
- if s is empty string problem solved (return True)
- if t is empty the problem solved (return False)
- if first letters match => return result of matching after first letters in s & t
- otherwise, match s after first letter in t

*Code*

```
def isSubsequence(s, t):
    # Base Cases
    if not s:
        return True  # s is empty
    elif not t:
        return False  # t is empty
    # Recursive case
    # if first letters match, solve after first letters of s & t
    # else find s after first letter of t
    return isSubsequence(s[1:], t[1:]) if s[0] == t[0] else isSubsequence(s, t[1:])
```

**Step 2: Analysis**

- The recursion provides a simple implementation
- Normally recusion would be inefficient since it would repeatedly solve the same subproblems over and over
- However, subproblems are not repeatedly solved in this case

For instance to find if "ab" is a subsequence of "xaxb" we the following call tree:

```
isSubsequence("ab", 'xaxb')         # to check "ab" against "xaxb"
  isSubsequence("ab", "axb")          # we check these sequence of subproblems
    isSubsequence("b", "xb")            # but each is only checked once
        isSubsequence("b", "b")
          isSubsequenc("", "")
            return True
```

**Step 3: Optimization**

In this case the solution is already optimized.  For other recursive solutons like thiw we would use memoization to optimize

- avoids repeatedly solving subsolutions
- can use the [cache](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html) Python 3.9+ or lru_cache (pre Python 3.9) for memoization

*Memoized Code* (note: not necessary in this case)

```
   from functools import lru_cache
    
    @lru_cache(maxsize=None)
    def isSubsequence(s, t):
        # Base Cases
        if not s:
            return True  # s is empty
        elif not t:
            return False  # t is empty
        # Recursive case
        # if first letters match, solve after first letters of s & t
        # else find s after first letter of t
        return isSubsequence(s[1:], t[1:]) if s[0] == t[0] else isSubsequence(s, t[1:])
```